# How do I create a stored procedure that accepts a user Id and returns the user’s full name and occupation and 1 email address

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
delimiter $$

create procedure userInformation(in uID varchar(50), out fullname varchar(50), out job varchar(50), out email varchar(50))
begin
      select concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) into FULLNAME
      from users
      where userid = uID;

      select occupation into JOB
      from occupation
      join users on users.occupationID = occupation.occupationid
      where userid = uID;

      select useremail into EMAIL from useremail
      join users on useremail.userid = users.userid
      where userid = uID
      limit 1;

END$$

delimiter ;
call userInformation('00002380-3e3b-11e3-bbac-c42c03098f6c', @fullnam, @job, @email);
select @fullname, @job, @email;
```

I get this error when I try and call/select the procedure;

> Column 'userid' in where clause is ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you for formatting it correctly, was trying to figure out where to edit it @Gordon Linoff

Comment: you have a `userid` column into more than one table, use table names to solve it, it's the third select

Comment: The ambiguity is here, `join users on useremail.userid = users.userid
      where userid = uID`.  Not related to your question, but, if buddy has more than one email account, you are pulling a random one.  That might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing code in MySQL, here are three rules:

- Always qualify column names in queries.
- Always distinguish parameter names by naming conventions.
- Always distinguish local variables by naming conventions.

So, I would write the code more like this:

```
create procedure userInformation (
    in in_uID varchar(50),
    out out_fullname varchar(50),
    out out_job varchar(50),
    out out_email varchar(50)
   )
begin
      select concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname)
      into out_fullname
      from users u
      where u.userid = in_uID;

      select o.occupation
      into out_job
      from occupation o join
           users u 
           on u.occupationID = o.occupationid
      where u.userid = in_uID;

      select ue.useremail
      into out_email
      from useremail ue JOIN
           users u
           on ue.userid = u.userid
      where ue.userid = in_uID
      limit 1;
end$$
```

Comment: this almost worked, had to change "where o.userid = in_uID to where o.occupationid

Comment: Unknown column 'o.userid' in 'where clause' is what i get when i input this code, if do the change iget null in jobs

Comment: The occupation table doesn't have a userid(has an occupationID); the users table has the usersid and so does useremail table

Comment: Changed the o.userid to u.userid and it worked, thanks so much! i finally understand the material now!!